# Evaluate a Triple Integral enclosed by a cylinder and two planes

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble setting the bounds for this:

Evaluate the triple integral $\displaystyle \iiint x \, dV$, where the solid is enclosed by the cylinder $x^2 + z^2 = 4$ and the planes $y = 0$ and $y + z = 4$.

I came up with: $0 \leq y \leq 4-z$ , $-\sqrt{4-x^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$, $-2 \leq x \leq 2$.
Is this right?

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11168/290189) [Please use MathJax.](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189)  For some basic information about writing math at this site, see [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189). Please read [this post](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/290189) for writing a good question.

Comment: Just see your edit with the bounds. Yes it is correct.

Comment: FYI: Another way to express this integral would be as $$\int_{-2}^2 \int_0^{4-\sqrt{4-x^2}} \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}f(x,y,z)dzdydx+\int_{-2}^2\int_{4-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{4+\sqrt{4-x^2}}\int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{4-y}f(x,y,z)dzdydx$$ where $f(x,y,z)=x$ is your integrand.

Answer (score 1):

Please note the given function $f(x,y,z) = x$ is negative to the left of $YZ$ plane and positive to the right of it. Given the symmetry of the cylinder and the plane $y+z = 4$ wrt $YZ$ plane, your integral will most likely be zero. Here are the bounds -

$0 \leq y \leq 4-z$ (cut by the planes $y = 0, y + z = 4)$

$x^2 + z^2 = 4 \implies -\sqrt{4-x^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{4-x^2}$

And lastly $-2 \leq x \leq 2$.

Your integral order should be $\,dy \, dz \, dx$

Or use polar coordinates in $XZ$ plane,

$x = r \cos \theta, z = r \sin \theta, y$.

$0 \leq y \leq 4-r\sin\theta$

$0 \leq r \leq 2$

$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$.

Order of integral should be $\, dy \, dr \, d\theta$.